# Apply Fullscreen Media Query on Edge & Chrome

Tags: css

I wrote a simple media query in CSS for fullscreen videos and it applies my code in Firefox but not in Edge or Chrome.

The CSS code looks something like this:
`@media all and (display-mode: fullscreen) { .test { height: 250px; } }`.

I read that you can use `@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto)` to apply CSS code to Edge only but how do I say the browser should only apply the code on fullscreen?

Edit:

```
@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
    .test:fullscreen {
        height: 250px;
    }
}
```

I have a video with interactive elements in it and when the user watches the video on fullscreen I have to apply some CSS code to these elements which works in Firefox. The video is embedded in an iFrame, don't know if it's mentionable.

Answer (score 1):

You can find your answer here:

https://www.ryadel.com/css3-media-query-applicare-stili-internet-explorer-ie-ie6-ie11-firefox-chrome-safari-edge/

For example, try this:

> Microsoft Edge
>
> ```
> @supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
>     .selector {
>         property: value;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Chrome 29+:
>
> ```
> @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
>     .chrome {
>         property: value;
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the post, that was quick. So when coding CSS for Edge and wanting to apply the code just for fullscreen I edited my code above but didn't work. Any ideas why?

Comment: @HansMartin Post your entire code, so we can help you

Comment: Don't know if the rest of the code is helpful for you because the other CSS code works and I see the changes in Firefox. I edited my answer again with some more content, maybe it's helpful. If I am wrong then I can post the whole CSS code but I don't see how it's gonna help you to understand the problem since I posted the questionable code above.

Comment: Is it even possible to apply CSS code only to edge on fullscreen mode?

Comment: @HansMartin Maybe it's possible.

Comment: Do you have any hints? :)